# Another important trend has been. Is it a complete sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

**Another important trend has been to reduce the number of platforms used for car models, as Japanese producer have long been doing.**

Is it correct/complete sentence? My question is about *Another important trend has been???? * If I cut out the adjunct *To reduce the number of platforms used for car models, as Japanese producer have long been doing* from the sentence, the main sentance would be **Another important trend has been** Is it a complete sentence? Isn't it passive sense?? If It's a passive sentence, after *Has been * whether  something is required or not??

Comment: I find the meaning behind that sentence slightly odd. If something has been happening for a long time, then it can't really be considered a *trend*, since that's normally something in the short-term—unless you're looking at a *progression* rather than a simple *yes/no*. (For example, it would make more sense to say *as Japanese producers have* ***increasingly*** *been doing for a long time.* In other words, it's not a short-term thing, but there's a steadily increasing trend. (If you were to graph it, a line would go roughly from the bottom left to the top right.)

Answer (score 1):

You are not correctly identifying an adjunct. The sentence parses initially as:

> (Another important trend) has been (to reduce the number of platforms used for car models), (as Japanese producers have long been doing).

The principal verb is ***has been***, and the infinitive clause is the object/complement. "Another important trend" is the subject.