# Has been+complement-VS-has+pp+object

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

1. **Another important trend has been to reduce the number of platforms used for car models, as Japanese producers have long been doing.**
2. **Another important trend has reduced the number of platforms used for car models, as Japanese producers have long been doing.**

Both are present perfect tense, aren't they? Are they correct sentences? Do  they have the same meaning?

Comment: Actually I want to know whether it has different meaning or not in the followings "Another important trend HAS BEEN TO REDUCE,,,,,,-vs-Another important trend HAS REDUCED,,,,,,"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Another important trend has been. Is it a complete sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/197599/another-important-trend-has-been-is-it-a-complete-sentence)

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. The "has been" you inserted into the former sentence makes it appear as if the trend has been going on for a while now, even outside of Japan, while the latter does not.Neither suggest that the trend is still relevant, either.The latter sentence, makes more sense for me to read, because it suggests that outside of Japan, this trend is relatively new, and doesn't repeat itself. Your former sentence is essentially saying

> This manufacturing trend has been important everywhere , and has been important in Japan too